# Unix: Using the xxd Command on a ppm File

Tags: files, xxd

I am fairly new to unix and am having trouble understanding what some of the commands do.For example, when I use `xxd` on a ppm file (i.e. `xxd image.ppm`) I get an output like this:

```
00000000: 5036 0a31 3131 2031 3332 0a32 3535 0a55  P6.111 132.255.U
00000010: 6137 5966 3958 6939 566a 3953 6739 5464  a7Yf9Xi9Vj9Sg9Td
00000020: 3b57 643a 5763 3654 6335 5161 334e 5c30  ;Wd:Wc6Tc5Qa3N\0
00000030: 4f5a 3250 5d35 5361 3556 6334 5561 3352  OZ2P]5Sa5Vc4Ua3R
00000040: 5e32 515d 3256 6035 5b64 3856 6136 4a55  ^2Q]2V`5[d8Va6JU
...
...
```

Can someone please explain to me what this output represents?

Comment: to find out what a command does, read its man page...don't just randomly run it - in many/most cases, that will be harmless.  in some cases, it could alter or even wipe your input file. or much worse.  e.g. run `man xxd` to find out what `xxd` does.

Comment: @cas, though, [the man page for xxd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) doesn't really describe what the output is, it just assumes the user knows what a common hexdump looks like :)

Comment: True, but "hexdump" is such a basic, well-known term that it's self-explanatory.  or should be :-).   BTW, I generally use `hexdump -C` or `hd` rather than `xxd` - more flexible output options and, IMO, better documented.

Comment: hexdump is probably not self-explanatory but it can be looked up.

Comment: That what I miss most from my Ultrix days; `man` had examples of commands.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro But... `man xxd` does provide examples down the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

The three parts are the offset from the start of the input, in hex; the data in hex; and the data in characters, if they're printable. 16 bytes to a line, since it's a nice round number and fits nicely on a screen.

A display like that is very often used in cases where both the binary and the textual data may be important. E.g. `tcpdump -X`  uses a similar one.

On your first line:

```
00000000: 5036 0a31 3131 2031 3332 0a32 3535 0a55  P6.111 132.255.U
```

The offset `00000000` is zero, since this is the beginning; `50`, `36`, and `0a` are the character codes for `P`, `6`, and the newline, and so on. Unprintable characters are printed as dots on the right hand column.

---

Note that in some variants, the bytes in the middle section may be "inverted" within each group. This happens if the program interprets the input as little-endian numbers, and displays them as such, instead of as individual bytes concatenated.

`xxd -e` does exactly this. Consider:

```
$ printf  "ABCD" | xxd -e -g2 
00000000: 4241 4443                                ABCD
```

`41` for `A`, and `42` for `B` appear in an inverted order, as well as the two others. `od` from GNU coreutils also inverts the bytes within the groups. When in doubt, double-check, or aim to get a one-by-one grouping. (compare e.g. `od -x` and `od -tx1` in this.)

---

Of course, the meaning of the data itself can be found out from the documentation for the ppm format. My system has the man page `ppm(5)`. (the online [version on die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ppm) has broken formatting.)

From that first line we can tell it's an RGB picture of size 111x132 pixels with 8-bits per sample.

Comment: +1 for referencing the `ppm` man page.  i was too lazy :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a hex dump, in a fairly common hexdump format, with each line of output containing the byte offset (in hexadecimal*), hex digits for 16 bytes, and the ASCII representation of those same bytes.

* Note how the byte offset increments by 0x10 hex (16 decimal) for each line.

From `man xxd`:

> **NAME**
>
> ```
>    xxd - make a hexdump or do the reverse.
> ```
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    xxd -h[elp]
>    xxd [options] [infile [outfile]]
>    xxd -r[evert] [options] [infile [outfile]]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `xxd`  creates  a  hex  dump of a given file or standard input.  It can also convert a hex dump back to its original binary
>   form.  Like `uuencode`(1) and `uudecode`(1) it allows the transmission of binary data in a 'mail-safe' ASCII  representation,
>   but has the advantage of decoding to standard output.  Moreover, it can be used to perform binary file patching.
>   [...]

hex dumps are extremely useful when you need to know exactly which bytes are in a file at some exact location.  They can help to diagnose problems where, for example, there are unexpected bytes (e.g. NULs (`0x00`) or carriage-returns (`0x0D`)) in the file and, as @ilkkachu mentions in his answer if the binary file format is documented (or you happen to know it anyway), it is often possible to interpret specific meanings for bytes in specific offsets (locations).